# How do I parse date with 12-hour format on AWS Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Can someone help me how can I convert this column to a date format? Quicksight is recognizing this as string.

I have something that looks like this. My file is a spreadsheet dump on S3.

```
1/6/2022 8:11:12 AM
1/5/2022 3:38:37 PM
1/5/2022 11:27:01 AM
1/4/2022 3:42:26 PM
```

I have tried parse date function but it skipped all my rows after. Please help.

```
parseDate({Date}, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following worked for me -

```
parseDate({Dates},'m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')
```

Refer  output below -

[image]